# How to I install zabbix-agent over apt-get

Tags: debian, apt

Why is it that on my Ubuntu 13.04 system I can easilly install **zabbix-agent** by doing `apt-get install zabbix-agent`.
When I do it in Debian 7.1, it says that the package zabbix-agent can not be found.

I run Zabbix version 2.0.8 on the zabbixserver.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`zabbix-agent` package is only available in the `wheezy-backports` repository, you should enable this repository if you want the software in wheezy (stable).

http://packages.debian.org/wheezy-backports/zabbix-agent

The package is also available in jessie (testing) and sid (unstable).

The procedure to enable the wheezy backports is adding:

```
deb http://YOURMIRROR.debian.org/debian wheezy-backports main
```

(replacing `YOURMIRROR` with your real mirror)

to your `sources.list`, then run `apt-get update` to update your repositories then installing the packages using your preferred apt method.

```
sudo apt-get install zabbix-agent
```

Normally to install packages from backports you need to specify that you want them with the `-t` switch, since all backports are deactivated by default (i.e. the packages are pinned to 100 by using `ButAutomaticUpgrades: yes` in the Release files.), but in this case, there shouldn't be problems because is the only version of the package available.

Comment: What are the downsides if i add this repository?

Comment: There is none, your system will not select packages from this repository unless you specifically ask for them.

Comment: Works perfectly!